# Scatter chart Play Axis is limited to 10 elements

Tags: powerbi

In a Power Bi report I'm using a Scatter Chart (bubble) with a Play Axis (months).

But this one is limited to 10 elements (I tried years, days, weeks... always 10). Also it's not a size problem, I already tried to put it on maximum size.

And I would like to have 12 elements (all months). How can I fix that?

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkW7f.png]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The scatter chart does not limit the play axis to 10 items, the value for those remaining items are null/blank due to which the play axis does not show those values. Please find below the screenshot. So please check the data for those missing categories. [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have no "null/blank" problem.

If I select january - october it's ok
If I select march - december it's also ok

But when I try to add an 11th element it fails